# Rails export multiple csv in same view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two csv exports on the same view, both with different data. Currently it's just downloading the same data for both.

**View**

```
<%= link_to "Trials export", data_path(format: "csv") %>
<%= link_to "Results export", data_path(format: "csv") %>
```

**Controller**

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv { send_data @trial_data.trials_export, filename: "trials_export.csv" }
  format.csv { send_data @trial_data.results_export, filename: "results_export.csv" }
end
```

**Model**

```
def self.trials_export
  csv << [ data goes in here all work fine ]
end

def self.results_export
  csv << [ data goes in here all work fine ]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your link_to you can add additional data / parameters for example format_data (variable name can be anything)

**View**

```
<%= link_to "Trials export", data_path(request.parameters.merge({:format => :csv, format_data: "trial"})) %>
<%= link_to "Results export", data_path(request.parameters.merge({:format => :csv, format_data: "result"})) %>
```

in your controller inside csv block you can split it with if / case command

**Controller**

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv do 
    if (params[:format_data] == 'trial')
      send_data @trial_data.trials_export, filename: "trials_export.csv"
    elsif (params[:format_data] == 'result')
      send_data @trial_data.results_export, filename: "results_export.csv" 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: ```export = "#{params[:format_data]}_export";
send_data(@trial_data.public_send(export), filename: "#{export}.csv")```

Comment: Yep, that's it. Cheers @widjajayd. Just to note: I didn't need the "request.parameters.merge" option.